# ¿Cómo debería formular la consulta?

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql

Tengo una tabla **provincias** con los campos: **autonomia, provincia, superficie y poblacion**.

Para sacar el nombre compuesto de las provincias, por ejemplo, *La coruña*, **¿Estaría bien poner lo siguiente?**:

```
SELECT provincia FROM provincias WHERE provincia LIKE '% %'
```

Comment: Si con compuesto te refieres a donde aparezca, si esta bien. El Like actúa como filtrador, te devolverá todos los resultados donde provincia contenga lo que pases como parámetro (en tu caso "La Coruña") Independientemente de en que posición se encuentre.
Por otro lado si solo quieres traer "La Coruña" como resultado yo puntualmente te recomendaría utilizar el signo de igual ('=')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto esa sintaxis, otra podría ser

```
SELECT provincia FROM provincias WHERE provincia REGEXP '.';
```

Utilizando lenguajes regulares. Visita [ http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx ] para mas detalles.

Comment: muchas gracias majo. Que tengas un buen día.